# Ternary Search Tree - Iterative Traversal

Tags: java, algorithm

I am trying to traverse a `ternary search tree` iteratively. I am trying to traverse it using the same techniques as used for a binary search tree, keep a stack, `push` a node, `pop` it, and `push` its children.

This way, all the nodes are visited, but i am not sure how can i keep track of what Strings does the tree contain.

I have a recursive code for traversal :

```
public void traverse(TernaryTreeNode r, String str)
    {
        if (r != null)
        {
            traverse(r.left, str);

            str = str + r.data;
            if (r.isEnd)
                al.add(str);

            traverse(r.middle, str);
            str = str.substring(0, str.length() - 1);

            traverse(r.right, str);
        }
    }
```

I wish to rewrite an iterative implementation.
This is the current code :

```
public void iterativePreorder(TernaryTreeNode node) {

        // Base Case
        if (node == null) {
            return;
        }

        // Create an empty stack and push root to it
        Stack<TernaryTreeNode> nodeStack = new Stack<TernaryTreeNode>();
        nodeStack.push(root);
        String str = "";

        while (nodeStack.empty() == false) {

            // Pop the top item from stack and print it
            TernaryTreeNode mynode = nodeStack.peek();
            nodeStack.pop();
            str+= mynode.data;
            if(mynode.isEnd){
                al.add(str); //al is an ArrayList of strings
            }

            // Push right and left children of the popped node to stack
            if (mynode.right != null) {
                nodeStack.push(mynode.right);
            }

            if (mynode.middle != null) {
                nodeStack.push(mynode.middle);
            }
            else{
                str = "";
            }

            if (mynode.left != null) {
                nodeStack.push(mynode.left);
            }


        }

    }
```

based on the `isEnd` property, i am able to know whether the current node denotes an End of String, and so i add the `str` to the arraylist. (the isEnd may or may not be a leaf node). but i am not able to define the logic for getting all strings, using `str`.

This is the TernaryTreeNode class :

```
public class TernaryTreeNode {

    char data;
    boolean isEnd;
    TernaryTreeNode left, middle, right;

    public TernaryTreeNode(char data){
        this.data = data;
        this.isEnd = false;
        this.left = this.middle = this.right = null;
    }
}
```

here is a visual example : 
http://igoro.com/archive/efficient-auto-complete-with-a-ternary-search-tree/

Comment: What exactly does _keep track of what Strings does the tree contain_ mean? As I see you're concatenating strings from all nodes to a single string. If this is what you want then what's wrong with the code? Also `str = "";` looks suspisios, maybe this is the problem?

Comment: @NikolayKondratyev keeping track of the strings --> based on the isEnd property, i am able to know whether the current node denotes an End of String, and so i add the str to the arraylist. the isEnd may or may not be a leaf node. so, after adding a string, i have to reinitialize somewhere to get the other strings as well. i am not able to define that logic in code.

Comment: Then I guess you just need to move `str = "";` after `al.add(str);`. You go throw a tree, and if node marked as `isEnd` you need to add string to a list and at the same time reset current string `str` to an empty one.

Comment: @NikolayKondratyev i am not sure if you are aware of the ternary search tree functionality, but that won't work in this case, as strings would also contain other strings, for example, AB and ABBA, once i reach AB, i cannot reinitialize str, as i also need to get ABBA

Comment: Do not "accumulate" `String`s, use [`StringBuilder.append()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#append-java.lang.Object-). (And don't name or declare variable to reflect their implementation type: `Collection<String> strings` instead of `al`, (or `List`, _if_ `Collection` "can't do it").)

Comment: @greybeard here is an example : http://igoro.com/archive/efficient-auto-complete-with-a-ternary-search-tree/
(It would be easier to actually walk through the example, then trying to explain it in the question)

Comment: I don't see a _ternary tree_ in the page linked, but advise to take  the information therein with a grain of salt.

Comment: @greybeard the one mentioned in "Ternary tree to the rescue"

Comment: (Put _in the question_ that you have a working(?) recursive implementation, and motivate _just why_ you are trying to come up with an iterative one.) As an alternative to manipulating a stack of strings, consider to have _one_ `StringBuilder` (and a stack of lengths, if going from trie to _prefix tree_).

Comment: @greybeard yeah, this question isn't strrictly about the ternary tree as mentioned in your wikipedia link (it is a more general purpose definition), but any search for 'ternary search tree' would probably get us the correct specific links.

Answer (score 1):

You may consider keeping another **Stack** to keep track of the string from the parent or use the same **Stack** with a paired class.

```
class TernaryPair {
  TernaryTreeNode node;
  String fromParent;
}
```

Root element put into the stack with an empty string. Whenever you push a string into the stack you also push the string from the parent.

```
TernaryPair mypair = nodeStack.pop();
str+= mypair.fromParent + mypair.node.data;
if(mypair.node.isEnd){
  al.add(str); //al is an ArrayList of strings
}
```

and when pushing to the stack

```
if (mypair.node.right != null) {
  TernaryPair newPair = new TernaryPair();
  newPair.node = mypair.node.right;
  newPair.fromParent = str;
  nodeStack.push(newPair);
}
```

**PS:** `Stack pop()` method will **remove and return** you the element at the top of the stack. A single call is enough.

```
TernaryTreeNode mynode = nodeStack.peek();
nodeStack.pop();
```

-->

```
TernaryTreeNode mynode = nodeStack.pop();
```

Comment: hey, thanks, i did consider this, but i thought it would be too much of a change in structure.
I already have a recursive implementation, and i am wiling to keep the iterative one as close as possible
any help with implementation of 'You may consider keeping another Stack to keep track of the string from the parent' ?